# No hashing while trying to Hash using Python BCrypt

Tags: python, django, hash, bcrypt

I have a **view** like:

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPass = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']

            hashedpasswithsalt = bcrypt.hashpw(clearPass, bcrypt.gensalt(14))

            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })
```

**RegistrationForm**

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    userPass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['userNm','userPass']
```

Why is it storing in plaintext?

I'm trying to take the `cleaned_data[]` of `userPass` from a modelfrom and hash it prior to sending to the db.

Comment: Try: from django.utils import force_unicode clearPass = force_unicode(RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `bcrypt.hashpw(clearPass.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt(14))`.

This is because your clearPass is by default an Unicode object and that it can't be directly used in your hashing function, the `encode("utf-8")` converts it into a standard string and then it can be hashed.

Comment: This seems to work, but the password is still stored in plaintext. Any reason why ?

Comment: Yes, Im sure they are being stored in plaintext still. I think it is because 'hashedpasswithsalt' isn't assigned to' RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']   '

Comment: Unfortunately it is still being stored as plaintext.